# Distribute In-House iOS App through Microsoft Intune

Tags: ios, sccm, enterprise-distribution, intune

We have developed an iOS app that we would like to distribute through [Microsoft Intune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/microsoft-intune/).

We have already subscribed to the [iOS Developer Enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) and created an *In-House Distribution* provisioning profile used to sign our application which is then deployed to Intune.

Using the portal Intune app installed from the Apple app store, our developed  app is not displayed in the available app list.

What do we have to do to make our app visible in Intune in order to be installed?

Do we have to install the Distribution certificate somewhere in Intune?

Do we need to use the [Intune app wrapping tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45218)?

We already knew that we could view the app through safari, but I thought that, using the In-House Distribution provisioning, we could directly use the Intune App to distribute our production ready app.

We have other "still in development" iOS app that we distribute through Intune using a Development provisioning which we update by hand adding the Test devices.

***Anyway, even accessing from Safari, the process of installing the deployed app fails.***

Comment: Are you able to connect a device to a computer and view the phone's console output as you install? You can get to it through Xcode or iPhone Configuration Utility as per this post: http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/294kj4/where_did_the_console_from_devices_go_in_xcode_6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on MS Technet. Does it shed any light on your problem?

> Currently, end-users cannot install corporate apps from the Microsoft Intune Company Portal app for iOS. This is due to restrictions placed on apps that are published in the iOS App Store (see App Store Review Guidelines, Section 2). Users can access corporate apps (including managed App Store apps and line-of-business app packages) by launching the Company Portal app on their device and tapping the Company Apps tile, which will open Safari browser and redirect them to the Intune Web Portal. For more information about the mobile management capabilities enabled by the Intune Company Portal app, see Mobile Device Management Capabilities in Microsoft Intune.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-add