# Xcode: creating an app for a client to distribute with their MS InTune

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, intune

We have an app listed on the Apple AppStore and a client wants to use a previous version of our app that was already listed on the AppStore. I exported an AppStore version of the .ipa from Xcode and sent that to them. But for them to use it with MS InTune, they had to re-sign the app and create a new app id, which messed up our deeplinks.

Is there a way to export the .ipa file from Xcode for them to use in MS InTune so that they don't need to resign the app? Or maybe there is an ipa file I can download from AppStore Connect?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334068/distribute-in-house-ios-app-through-microsoft-intune) about In House distribution, but they are a client and so as I understand it, In House does not apply.